# How can I define a name and then change it while reading a file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do something like that:

```
name = 'jack'
df =  pd.read_excel(name, +, "Listing(2016) Rev.2.xlsx", skiprows=3)
```

My goal is to change the name and then read the file based on the name.
I have three names for example.

- 'jack'
- 'John'
- 'nick'

I received the following error:

```
> File "<ipython-input-39-85237a57057f>", line 1
    dat = pd.read_excel(name, +, "Listing(2016) Rev.2.xlsx", skiprows=3)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help?

Comment: You want to read 3 separate workbooks? Or 3 separate worksheets in the same workbook?

Comment: I want to change only the name every time for a different name.

Comment: it should be `dat = pd.read_excel(name + "Listing(2016) Rev.2.xlsx", skiprows=3)`

Answer (score 4):

```
name = 'jack'
excel_name = "{}Listing(2016) Rev.2.xlsx".format(name)
df =  pd.read_excel(excel_name, skiprows=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use commas with `+` for strings:

```
dat = pd.read_excel(name + "Listing(2016) Rev.2.xlsx", skiprows=3)
```